# Display a taxonomy term every number of rows

Tags: views

I have a view with Infinite Scroll Pager giving me the latest products of the website.

Every taxonomy term has an image attatched on it.

I want to display taxonomy terms every 3 rows of products.

Comment: What version of drupal do you use?

Comment: @AlirezaTabatabaeian thanks for commenting. I am on 7.

Comment: and do you have coding skills? I think you will need to write some code to achieve functionality you desire

Comment: yes, I might need to alter the views but that's no problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you must alter the view.

1. Create the views normally, add taxo to every rows.
2. Use the Hook hook_views_pre_render(&$view)
3. Delete the term for every rows except 1/3.

For example something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'view_myviewname') {
    $result = $view->result;
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($result as $i => $row) {
      if(!$count % 3){
        unset($view->result[$i]->field_MYTEXONOMYFIELD[0]);
      }
      $count++;
    }
  }
}
```

Example from : http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/238/alter-a-view-edit-view-result-programmatically